# Unable To Break Out Of While Loop When Using Pynput.mouse

Tags: python, while-loop, break, pynput

I have this relatively simple program that listens for mouse clicks and when the mouse button is held down prints "1"s. Unfortunately when I let go of the mouse it just keeps printing "1"s, even though there is an if statement which checks if the mouse is clicked and should stop the loop if it is not. I am using the `pynput.mouse` module for the mouse interaction.

Here is my code:

```
import time
from pynput.mouse import Listener

def clicked(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed == True:
        while button == button.left:
            print("1")
            time.sleep(1)
            if pressed == False:
                break




with Listener(on_click=clicked) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

My theory is that once the loops starts it stops listening for mouse clicks, so it can never stop the loop. Would it be necessary to create a new thread for the loop? If yes, how would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You only enter the while loop if `pressed == True`, and nothing is changing the value of `pressed` - so how could `if pressed == False` ever evaluate to `True` if you've already proven that impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current logic makes it impossible to get out of the loop, since `pressed` doesn't change within the loop.  There is *not* a statement that checks if the mouse is clicked: your only `if` statements check whether the mouse was clicked when you entered the function.  `pressed` doesn't change within the function.

Look at the critical logiic:

```
if pressed == True:
    while ...
        ...
        if pressed == False:
            break
```

There is nothing in here to change the value of `pressed`; the first `if` guarantees that it's `True` anywhere within the loop.

Yes, you need to set up another listener that operates within the loop.  You already know the building blocks: create a new one within the function and bind it to another operation that breaks the loop.  For instance, you might "cheat" and have it reset `pressed` as a global variable.

You could also research how to do this in other answers, if you want an overall handler solution.  keypress and keyrelease have been done often enough.

Comment: I've understood the problem with my code, but as a beginner I am having trouble understanding what I should do to fix it. By another listener do you mean a new function that checks for changes in` pressed` or something like a` threading.Timer` that checks it? Also what do mean by reset `pressed` as a global variable? I can't make it global since it is already a parameter in `clicked`. I'm sorry for the confusion, I just want to get it straight so that I don't have to ask the next time I encounter a problem like this. Some example code would help.

Comment: Most of what you ask for is tutorial help, beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.  Briefly, what I'm suggesting is (1) Look up how others handle the start and release of an external event.  (2) If you want to stay with your current set-up, embed a new `Listener` and function within `clicked`.  Then `pressed` can be a global variable to that embedded function.

Comment: Thank you, the last part cleared things up for me. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui, random, time
import pynput 

keys = ['w', 's', 'a', 'd']


def on_press(key):
    p = True
    if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False

    else:
        while p == True:
            press = keys[random.randint(0,3)]
            pyautogui.keyDown(press)
            pyautogui.keyUp(press)
            p = False            

        
with pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as  L:
    L.join()
```

a code like this will work instead of what you did.
BTW, that is just an example; feel free to visit my GitHub page: github.com/ironnicko